# Concatenate string literals at compile time

Tags: c++17, variadic-templates, string-concatenation, constexpr-function

I need to concatenate a variable number of string literals into one to use it in static_assert()

I tried using templates with structs, but compiler does not like literals as template parameters.

```
error: the address of ‘m1’ is not a valid template argument because it does not have static storage duration.
error: ‘"thre"’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const char*’ because string literals can never be used in this context
```

I also tried perfect forwarding, but I get an error: `‘args#0’ is not a constant expression`

```
template<size_t size>
constexpr size_t const_strssize(const char (&)[size]) {
        return size;
}

template<class... Ts> 
constexpr size_t const_strssize(Ts&&... args) {
        return const_sum<(const_strssize(std::forward<const Ts>(args)), ...)>::get;
}
```

Just to clarify, I cannot do `"string1" "string2"` because some of the strings I get from functions returns.

Please, do not advise stuff like strlen or memcpy. I know, they can be calculated at compile time.

Comment: C++20 NTTP can do this, do you have a more concrete example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static_assert()` is specified to accept string literal. Any constexpr function you can write can return a constant, but not literal. So you only may use preprocessor to construct strings for `static_assert`. Sorry.